# Spacy - apply similarity function to documents in pandas rows

Tags: python, pandas, spacy

I have a question regarding similarity() operation over documents stored in pandas series (in rows). I tagged and extracted all nouns from documents, then passed them as a list of Tokens to another column. Now, I would want to calculate similarity between them. However, I have a problem (definitely some misunderstanding of spacy pipeline on my part) with types. I have something like this right now:

**Edit:**

I get my list of nouns from here:

```
def nouns_verbs(title_text):
    token_nouns = []
    token_verb = []

    title_text = nlp(title_text)

    for token in title_text:
        if token.pos_ == 'NOUN':
            token_nouns.append(token)
        elif token.pos_ == 'VERB':
            token_verb.append(token)
    return title_text, token_nouns, token_verb

new_df = df.ggg.apply(nouns_verbs)
df = pd.DataFrame([x for x in new_df], columns=['title', 'nouns', 'verbs'])
```

Example of df.nouns (remember, this is list of Tokens, not str):

```
0    [shipping, inc, time, charter, contract]
1    [telensa, lighting, solution, kingdom, ports]
2    [pioneer, export, gulf, coast, cfo]
```

For loop to find similarity between nouns in row_first and nouns in row_second

```
for row_first, row_second in itertools.combinations(df.nouns, 2):
    n1 = [nlp(x.text) for x in row_first]
    n2 = [nlp(x.text) for x in row_second]
    sim = n1.similarity(n2)
    print('N1:', n1, 'N2:', n2, 'SIM', sim)
```

This complains:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'similarity'
```

How should I construct my loop to compare each noun from row_first to each noun in row_second? If I iterate over tokens, like this

```
[nlp(x.text) for x in row_first for x in x]
```

I still get a TypeError `TypeError: 'spacy.tokens.token.Token' object is not iterable`. But even if - I want to compare row by row, not token by token.

Follow up question is: Does it have sense to compare nouns to nouns like this for similarity? As I understand word2vec compares vector spaces, which means that it finds context relevant for similarity score (words which are repeatedly close to same words in many different contexts). In my model there is no context, only standalone words to compare (I was planing to then average this similarity score somehow, because I want to have few similarity scores for nouns, verbs and whole document).

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame(['i love playing football','good morning how are you'], columns = ['text'])
df['token'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: nlp(x))
```

for similarity your value should be spacy.tokens.doc.Doc and not list that why you are getting error. i think you might have used different tokenizer which is giving you list.
now you can simply join your list token and pass that string into your  spacy nlp model , which will give you the required type to calculate simialrity

```
print(type(df['token'][0]))
spacy.tokens.doc.Doc

sim = df['token'][0].similarity(df['token'][1])
#op
0.67807547218049
```

Comment: It works exactly like this if I use scikit-learn for POS tag (because it returns str). However, I would like to keep everything inside of spaCy pipeline and spaCy tagger returns Token. I updated my post with function I use for extracting nouns and verbs.